# xmlSerialize two lists of different objects

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I need help to serialize two lists and write them in a xml file.
The code I tried is

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<OtherAction>));
XmlSerializer xsActions = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Action>));
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("actions.xml"))
{
   xs.Serialize(sw, listOtherActions);
   xsActions.Serialize(sw, listActions);
}
```

But it writes listOtherActions, then listActions. So it creates 2 root on the xml file
What I want to do is having only one root node and my two lists inside.

Comment: If you have 2 different objects then serialize them as 2 different objects. Or write each serialization to string and put them in some xml manually.

Comment: What do you mean by serializing them as 2 different objects? I'm new with xmlserializer

Comment: Just deserialize them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a single class that would have both List types in it and serialize that class. like below.

```
public class Combined
{
 public List<OtherAction> otherActions{get; set;}
 public List<Action> actions{get; set;}
}


XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Combined>));
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("CombinedActions.xml"))
{
   xs.Serialize(sw, listCombinedActions);
}
```

Comment: my "Action" list is a polymorphic list with 10+ class in it. I don't know if the "Combined" class would be a good choice in that case. And I'll need to deserialize an xml file to get everything in my class back. I'm not sure if I could do that with your solution

Comment: If ur not sure then y not try it out. Just give it a try :)

Comment: Instead of making a combined object, I made a class containing both lists. Your solution brought me to this, so thank you :)